# Footer on Short Page, No Superflous Markup or Javascript

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out the best way to deal with a footer on a short page without using superfluous, unsemantic markup. I'm interested in being really pedantic about this. So, let's discuss:

The simplest option would be to allow the background color of the body extend beyond the footer. But, if your footer is a different color, this can look bad. [Simple Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1956363)

[Sticky footers](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) require the addition of a "push" element that has no semantic meaning. Yuck.

[Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)? Absurd.

Some sort of [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)? No background images.

Setting the `background-color` of the `body` or `html` to the color you want the `footer` to be, and "covering it up" with a full width wrapper `div` ([Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1956482)). I wouldn't have had those wrapper `div`s if I didn't want this effect. They add no semantic meaning.

Hmmm.

I've been experimenting with the new CSS3 flexbox, and I've cobbled together [this](http://dabblet.com/gist/1956380).

```
html{height:100%;}
body{display:box; box-orient:vertical; height:100%;}
header{height:50px; background:salmon;}
section{height:50px; /*height:2000px;*/}
footer{width:100%; min-height:100px; box-flex: 1; background:lightblue;}
```

It works exactly as I desire. When the content is too short to cause scrollbars, the footer fills the remaining space, and when there is much more content, it shrinks down to the `min-height` (not ideal). It works—in WebKit. Firefox handles `display: box` very strangely. For some reason you can't center elements that are `display: -moz-box`. Neither Opera nor IE support flexbox at this time. Also, it degrades gracefully, which is very much required.

I'm at an impasse. I could soil and clutter my markup, accept some graceful degradation in some modern browsers (by including *only* `display: -webkit-box`, `-webkit-box-flex`, etc), or change my design based on the limitations of CSS, but I don't want to make any of these compromises. Help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to use a Pseudo-element in your css you could do this:

```
footer:after { 
  background: lightblue; /*same color as footer*/
  content: "";   
  margin-top: 100px; /*height of footer. (prevents overlapping footer content)*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

No change in markup and it should work in most browsers.